# Windows Workflow 4 - learning questions

Tags: workflow-foundation

I started learning WF yesterday for a particular purpose. I'm not sure if WF fits the purpose at all. I have an algorithm with pluggable parts and I want to give the user the ability to choose what parts will be executed and about the order of execution.

I have constraints regarding data contracts between parts and some constraints on the order of executions (some parts cannot execute sooner than some others).

How can I apply these constraints to activities?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like WF is a good fit for the type of thing you are building.  You can implement design time constraints for your activities.  For more information see [Configuring Activity Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358728.aspx)